# Como posso alterar o código do botão submit?

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Olá,
Criei um formulário Contact form7 com código javascript e ao tentar enviá-lo não acontecia nada.
Ao consultar o código (inspeccionar elemento) do botão submit obtive o seguinte resultado:

```
<input id=enviar1 class=”wpcf-form-control wpcf7-submit” value=”enviar” disable=”disable” type=”submit”>
```

Ao remover a instrução ´disable=”disable”´ já consigo obter as mensagens. Agora tenho dois problemas:

1- Como remover definitivamente esta instrução

2- Embora tendo criado um campo aceitação para aceitar os termos, obtenho sempre a mensagem "Tem que aceitar os termos e condições antes de enviar a sua mensagem." esteja o campo on ou off.

Alguém me ajuda?

Comment: Onde está o código que cria esse formulário e esse botão?

Comment: O código está numa página que contém o shortcode de um formulário. Podes consultar o código do formulário nesta pergunta:http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/195982/formul%c3%a1rio-contact-form7-n%c3%a3o-existe-mensagem-de-erro-mas-o-formul%c3%a1rio-n%c3%a3o-%c3%a9-sub

Comment: Ah, estou a ver. Esses shortcodes são da API do `contact-form`. Espero que alguém conheça e possa ajudar. Entretanto acho que esta pergunta é a mesma que a outra certo?

Comment: Eu só coloquei esta pergunta porque o Sérgio referiu que não a deveria colocar como resposta à anterior mas que criasse uma nova pergunta...Desculpem a confusão...